# Getting error while configuring an IP masquerade agent for the Autopilot cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

We are getting below error while configuring an IP masquerade agent for the Autopilot cluster:

```
error: failed to create configmap: configmaps is forbidden: User "abc@gmail.com" cannot create resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system": GKEAutopilot authz: the namespace "kube-system" is managed and the request's verb "create" is denied
```

We followed [this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#using-gcloud-init) for the standard cluster and configured IP masquerade agent successfully.

But for the autopilot it is not working even though we choose region for the cluster as suggested in the above article.

Comment: What's your use case which requires ip masq agent?  Maybe we can figure out an alternative on Autopilot.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add a few things to what was already mentioned by Gari Singh in his answer. Keep in mind that **Autopilot** cluster due to its fully managed nature in comparison with **standard GKE cluster** has quite wide range of [workload limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#limits).

Although it is not mentioned explicitly in the docs that running **IP masquerade agent** on this type of cluster is not supported, it can be deduced from [this fragment](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#managed_namespaces) where you can read:

> The `kube-system` namespace is managed, meaning that all resources in
> this namespace cannot be altered and new resources cannot be created.

And this is basically what your **IP masquerade agent** is trying to do. The error message you get explains in fact the exact reason why it cannot be done:

```
...cannot create resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"...
...the namespace "kube-system" is managed and the request's verb "create" is denied...
```

However I fully agree that documentation probably needs some improvement as the following fragment in the [article you linked](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent):

> 5. Choose a default Compute Engine zone for zonal clusters or a region for regional or **Autopilot clusters**.

may suggest that it should also work on **Autopilot cluster**.

What I would suggest in such case is to [create a new issue on Google's public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) (search for **Kubernetes Engine** on the list), and request to remove the above fragment about **Autopilot** or even add an explicit information that IP masquerade agent is not supported on this type of cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion mario. I will try to create the issue

Answer (score 1):

IP masquerade agent is not currently supported on Autopilot clusters.

Comment: Thanks for the update Gari Singh

Comment: There is an open issue which we are already working on to address this

Comment: IP masquerade is in GKE Autopilot now and being created automatically:
[blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/ip-masquerading-and-ebpf-are-now-in-gke-autopilot), 
[doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/egress-nat-policy-ip-masq-autopilot#deploy-new-policy).

However, it seems there is an issue with the attempt to edit it via terraform: https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/issues/1578